# How do I use URLFetchApp to download a pdf of a tab in a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an Apps Script function that will produce a PDF of a given tab in a Google Sheets workbook. I've adapted Google's sample code from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/generate-pdfs. Specifically, the createPDF function is where they do what I'm looking for.

If I try to run the adapted code (see below) I get an HTTP 401 on the URLFetchApp call, even though I'm providing an OAuth token.

```
/**
 * Creates a PDF for the customer given sheet.
 * @param {string} ssId - Id of the Google Spreadsheet
 * @param {object} sheet - Sheet to be converted as PDF
 * @param {string} pdfName - File name of the PDF being created
 * @return {file object} PDF file as a blob
 */
function createPDF(ssId, sheet, pdfName) {
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 9, lr = 27;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" +
    "size=7&" +
    "fzr=true&" +
    "portrait=true&" +
    "fitw=true&" +
    "gridlines=false&" +
    "printtitle=false&" +
    "top_margin=0.5&" +
    "bottom_margin=0.25&" +
    "left_margin=0.5&" +
    "right_margin=0.5&" +
    "sheetnames=false&" +
    "pagenum=UNDEFINED&" +
    "attachment=true&" +
    "gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +
    "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r2=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc;

  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');

  // Gets the folder in Drive where the PDFs are stored.
  const folder = getFolderByName_(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME);

  const pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);
  return pdfFile;
}
```

If I create the url as above and paste it into a browser, I get the pdf I'm expecting. But if I just create a testing() function like so:

```
function testing() {
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[spreadsheetID-here]/export?format=pdf&size=7&fzr=true&portrait=true&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&top_margin=0.5&bottom_margin=0.25&left_margin=0.5&right_margin=0.5&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=true&gid=286847305&r1=0&c1=0&r2=27&c2=10"

  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName('hello.pdf');

  console.log(blob.getContentType());
}
```

Then I get a HTTP 401 in the console when I try to run the function. The 401 occurs on the URLFetchApp call.

I also tried just running Google's code in their Google Sheet, and it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

My script has the following scopes, which I think is all it needs (the send mail is because I intend to let the user send the pdf once I get it working):

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly

Comment: You need drive scopes(or spreadsheet scopes)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the ticket. Do you know which spreadsheet scope in particular? Just the “create/edit/delete all the user’s spreadsheets” one?

Comment: If you want to select the scopes with `appsscript.json`, in your script, if you use the scope of Sheets API, it is required to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`. Unfortunately, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` cannot be used. If you want to use `readonly`, I think that the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` can be used. You can select one of them.

Comment: @Tanaike that’s it! Drive.readonly works